# Vim syntax region on the first lines of a file

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, vim-syntax-highlighting

I try to create a syntax definition of my notes.

Here is an example:

```
=Title of the note (it's the very first line)
@context (mandatory)
!action (mandatory)
#tag-1 (optional)
#tag-2 (optional)
#tag-n (optional)
>attached-files (optional)

My note come after the first blank line
and continue until the end of the file...

No matter any additional empty line
```

I would like to create the syntax to highlight then theses differents matches. In my note, I can write lines which look like a title (= this way) or a tag (#this-way) and they don't have to be highlighted. I try to create a region for my note metadata going from the first line to the first empty line.

I tried this but I've got issues (highlight seems good but If I delete all lines after the empty line (the empty line included) then it doesn't work anymore...

```
augroup gtd

    autocmd!

    autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.gtd set filetype=gtd

    autocmd FileType gtd syntax region gtdTags start="\%1l" end="^\s*$" fold transparent contains=gtdTitle,gtdContext,gtdStatus,gtdHashtags,gtdAttachedFiles
    autocmd FileType gtd syntax match gtdTitle '^=.*' contained
    autocmd FileType gtd syntax match gtdContext '^@\S\+$' contained
    autocmd FileType gtd syntax match gtdStatus '^!\S\+$' contained
    autocmd FileType gtd syntax match gtdHashtags '^#\S\+$' contained
    autocmd FileType gtd syntax match gtdAttachedFiles '^>attached-files$' contained

    autocmd FileType gtd syntax match gtdSubtitle '^\s*\*\* .*'
    autocmd FileType gtd syntax keyword gtdTodo TODO WAITING SOMEDAY SCHEDULED

    autocmd FileType gtd highlight gtdTitle guifg=white guibg=NONE gui=bold
    autocmd FileType gtd highlight gtdContext guifg=yellow
    autocmd FileType gtd highlight gtdStatus guifg=red gui=NONE
    autocmd FileType gtd highlight gtdHashtags guifg=grey gui=italic
    autocmd FileType gtd highlight gtdAttachedFiles guifg=red guibg=white gui=bold

    autocmd FileType gtd highlight gtdSubtitle guifg=black guibg=lightgrey gui=bold
    autocmd FileType gtd highlight gtdTodo guifg=white guibg=red gui=NONE

augroup END
```

How to stop the region on the first empty/blank line or at the end of the file, regarding the first which is coming ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could include the special atom representing the end of the file in your pattern for the region end: `end="^\s*$\|\@$"`; however, this isn't necessary. Vim *always* starts a syntax region when the `start` pattern matches; it does not check for the `end` pattern, as `:help syn-region` explains:

> Note: The decision to start a region is only based on a matching start
>     pattern.  There is no check for a matching end pattern.

So, all regions implicitly end at the end of the buffer, even if there's no match for the `end` pattern. And in fact, your syntax works for me just fine.

I think you've got confused because you did not define a proper syntax script, and instead chose the `autocmd FileType gtd` prefixes. Also, the `syntax clear` is missing.

Place your `:syntax` commands into a separate file in `~/.vim/syntax/gtd.vim`, and adhere to the format described at `:help 44.12`. You can also have a look at one of the various syntax scripts in `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/*.vim` that ship with Vim.